# jQuery autocomplete option shows for a split of second and then hides

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using `jQuery autocomplete` for address field. I send search query to `JSP` which works with Java back-end which returns back a `JSON` formatted `String`. I want to use new source of data by each keystroke user types, so I am trying to refresh the `String` of autocomplete options.

It works, but matching option shows only for a split of a second.

Basically what I want is to replace `JSON String` while user types, since I have database containing many addresses.

Main HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js">  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var addresses=['Freyas Kvarter'];
  function lookupDone(param){
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
      lookup: addresses
    });
   }
function sendSearchRequest(searchQuery){
  var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://localhost:8080    
  /FIBIA_Autocomplete/main.jsp?search=" + searchQuery);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#autocomplete").keyup(function() {
    sendSearchRequest($("#autocomplete").val());
  });
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: addresses
  });
});
</script>
```

It is not a complex question as it might look, I am getting correct values to addresses value after each keystroke, but somehow autocomplete is not working as expected. I have already saw many questions in regards to that, but nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had used wrong library... `lookup` should be replaced with `source` and `js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js` should be replaced with `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js`

Hope it will help somebody else in a future.